# Compared counted data from the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2, and I am trying to compare counted results from the same query I ran the following:

```
select 
    e.JobTitle,
    COUNT(p.BusinessEntityID) [NO. of persons]
from 
    AdventureWorks2008.person.Person p with (Nolock)
join 
    AdventureWorks2008.HumanResources.Employee e with (nolock) on e.BusinessEntityID = p.BusinessEntityID
group by 
    e.JobTitle
```

I get the following results as expected:

```
JobTitle                        NO. Of persons
Accountant                                   2
Accounts Manager                             1
Accounts Payable Specialist                  2
Accounts Receivable Specialist               3
Application Specialist                       4
Assistant to the Chief Financial Officer     1
Benefits Specialist                          1
Buyer                                        9
Chief Executive Officer                      1
Chief Financial Officer                      1
Control Specialist                           2
Database Administrator                       2
Design Engineer                              3
Document Control Assistant                   2
Document Control Manager                     1
Engineering Manager                          1
```

What I want to do now is display the job title and count from these results where the count is the same, but the job title is not the same.

Basically Buyer would not be returned as there is no other group with a count of 9.

But Assistant to the Chief Financial Officer, Benefits Specialist among others would be returned as there are many job-titles with a count of 1.

What is the easiest and most efficient way to do this? thanks ahead.

Comment: Set [Bad Habits to kick - putting NOLOCK everywhere](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/) - it is ***NOT RECOMMENDED*** to use this everywhere - quite the contrary!

Comment: Its habit for me as i would be crucified for not using it. Many places have rules for queries and we wont have a say in the matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with cte:

```
with cte as(select e.JobTitle,
                   COUNT(p.BusinessEntityID) [NO. of persons]
            from AdventureWorks2008.person.Person p with (Nolock)
            join AdventureWorks2008.HumanResources.Employee e with (nolock) on e.BusinessEntityID = p.BusinessEntityID
            group by e.JobTitle)

select * from cte c1
where exists(select * from cte c2 
             where c2.[NO. of persons] = c1.[NO. of persons] and 
                   c2.JobTitle <> c1.JobTitle)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `join` to search for other rows with the same count but a different job title:

```
; with  List as 
        (
        ... your query here ...
        )
select  *
from    List l1
join    List l2
on      l1.[NO. of persons] = l2.[NO. of persons]
        and l1.JobTitle > l2.JobTitle -- Filter out duplicates
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a window function for this:

```
select *
from (select e.JobTitle,
             COUNT(p.BusinessEntityID) as [NO. of persons],
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY COUNT(*)) as count_with_count
     from AdventureWorks2008.person.Person p with (Nolock) join 
          AdventureWorks2008.HumanResources.Employee e with (nolock) 
          on e.BusinessEntityID = p.BusinessEntityID
     group by e.JobTitle
    ) jt
where count_with_count > 1
order by count_with_count;
```